# Auto populate ETL columns in PDM diagram while converting from LDM to PDM

Tags: data-modeling, erwin

We are trying to automate the process of adding some basic ETL pseudo columns like Job ID, ETL timestamp, Effective date etc.
While the post scripts can do it in the script template (expansion) but it does not displays in diagram when
we toggle from logical to physical.
Any guidance on achieving the above will be of great help.
Thanks,

We wrote a script in the script template and associated it at the model level , pre creation and saved it.